# Do not trust any user data in NGINX configs. How to resolve this error

Tags: nginx, devops, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-ingress, nginx-config

this is my nginx configuration for a frontend-Next.js application, in /etc/nginx/site-available/file.conf

```
        server {

                root /var/www/test.abc.com/;

                index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

                server_name test.abc.com;

                location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection ‘upgrade’;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
                add_header Cache-Control no-store;
                add_header Cache-Control must-revalidate;
                add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN always;
                add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
                add_header Set-Cookie "Path=/; HttpOnly; Secure";
                proxy_cookie_path / "/; secure";
                server_tokens off;
                add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains" always;
                }

                location ~ /\.git {
                deny all;
                }
            
        listen 443 ssl; 
            ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.abc.com/fullchain.pem; 
            ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.abc.com/privkey.pem; 
            include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; 
            ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; 

        }
        server {
            if ($http_host = test.abc.com) {
                return 301 https://$http_host$request_uri;
            } 

            server_name test.abc.com;
            listen 80;
            return 404;
            server_tokens off;
                }
```

But after code security scan I got this critical error, Any way to resolve it:

**Alert description:** The Cloud Metadata Attack attempts to abuse a misconfigured NGINX server in order to access the instance metadata maintained by cloud service providers such as AWS, GCP and Azure.All of these providers provide metadata via an internal unroutable IP address '176.544.122.111' - this can be exposed by incorrectly configured NGINX servers and accessed by using this IP address in the Host header field.
**Solution:**  Do not trust any user data in NGINX configs. In this case it is probably the use of the $host variable which is set from the 'Host' header and can be controlled by an attacker.

I've also tried to remove the **$http*host ****and Replace it with domain*url but NO LUCK!

Need help to resolve the issue for $Host in nginx.